# Is there a way to stop a function from executing when a certain condition is true?

Tags: javascript, function, api, conditional-statements

Here is the function. I want the function to stop running when the coditional statement is false. My conditional statement is suppose to return true when **countryName == input.value** but it never does and i want for a first time the function to stop running when the condtion is false

```
function generateRandomFlag() {
  return(
    fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
    .then((Response) => Response.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json);
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 250);
      flag.innerHTML = `
    <img src='${json[random].flags.png}'/>
    `;
      const countryName = (message.innerHTML = json[random].name.common);
      console.log(countryName);
      if ( countryName == input.value) {
        console.log(true);
      } else {
        console.log(false);
        
      }
    })
  )
}
generateRandomFlag()
```

I dont even know what to write to stop a function from running when a certain condition is true or false

Comment: Have you read before about js While ? you can easily achieve your goal using the [While](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop to only run the loop while a condition is true

Comment: What do you mean by "stop running"? There's no loop, the function just runs once.

Comment: Why not just pass the country name to the endpoint URL? **https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/{name_here}?fullText=true**

Comment: There are ways to stop a function from executing when a certain condition is true, but usually when people ask to do this it's either because their function is asynchronous and they want to cancel its execution, or because the function continues executing in some kind of a loop. It's unclear which, if either, of these applies in your case. Can you refine the question a little to be more clear?

Answer (score 0):

this page has very good examples of what you looking for.

https://flexiple.com/javascript/javascript-exit-functions/

I created an example using `Return` to exit the function if names do not match

```js
function  generateRandomFlag(){
var input = "usa";
 var countryName = "Canada";
 if (countryName != input) {
        console.log("will execute this line Hii");
       return;
        console.log("will not execute this line");
      } else {       
      console.log("Test");
      }
     }


generateRandomFlag()
```

Comment: This ignores the structure of the OP's code, which uses callbacks on Promises.